# mongodb member stuck in startup2

Tags: mongodb, recovery, replicaset

I have 3 nodes mongo replica set. one primary one secondary.
one node was down and didn't came up so I delete his data directory content  and start it (to force sync)
but the third node is stuck at STARTUP2 state and I keep getting these errors in his log:

```
: [ { durationMillis: 224240, status: "MaxTimeMSExpired: error fetching oplog during initial sync :: caused by :: error in fetcher batch
 callback :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit"
```

until I get this  and the node crashed:

```
2021-02-02T17:06:25.616Z F REPL     [replication-13] The maximum number of retries have been exhausted for initial sync.
2021-02-02T17:06:25.616Z I STORAGE  [replication-13] Finishing collection drop for local.temp_oplog_buffer (266f975f-2ae8-4ec4-a2b2-8304d13ef23d).
2021-02-02T17:06:25.623Z E REPL     [replication-13] Initial sync failed, shutting down now. Restart the server to attempt a new initial sync.
2021-02-02T17:06:25.623Z F -        [replication-13] Fatal assertion 40088 MaxTimeMSExpired: error fetching oplog during initial sync :: caused by :: error in fetcher batch callback :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit at src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp 703
2021-02-02T17:06:25.623Z F -        [replication-13]

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

can you please assist what can be done.!!

Comment: How big is the database and oplog ?   It looks like your database is under extensive write load and your  3th member is not able to catch for the duration of the oplog window ...

Comment: Also are the members close to each other or in different geographical location ?